# seeing through triangles in GLKit

Tags: opengl-es, glkit, depth-buffer

I am working on a simple iOS application to learn about OpenGLES 2.0.  In the project, I'm rendering 4 triangles in the shape of a pyramid, with some sliders to adjust the height of the apex of the pyramid, and to rotate the modalViewMatrix about the y axis.  I am trying to find the reason why.. after rotating this object counter-clockwise to the point where triangles appear in front of other triangles, I can see through the near triangles.  However, when rotating in the clockwise direction to the same point, the near triangles are opaque and occlude the furthest triangles.

I assumed that the reason was a lack of a depth render buffer but after setting the property `view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat16;` the behavior persists.

For reference, this is my drawRect function where drawing is done.  The only other code is done in viewDidLoad and in Global scope of the xcode project [here](https://github.com/AlexanderBollbach/ABGL1/blob/master/GLTest1/ViewController.m).

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

   [self.baseEffect prepareToDraw];

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,pos);



   glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

   const GLvoid * off1 = NULL + offsetof(SceneVertex, position) ;

   glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,               // Identifies the attribute to use
                         3,               // number of coordinates for attribute
                         GL_FLOAT,            // data is floating point
                         GL_FALSE,            // no fixed point scaling
                         sizeof(SceneVertex),         // total num bytes stored per vertex
                         off1);






   glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);


   const GLvoid * off2 = NULL + offsetof(SceneVertex, normal) ;

   glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal,               // Identifies the attribute to use
                         3,               // number of coordinates for attribute
                         GL_FLOAT,            // data is floating point
                         GL_FALSE,            // no fixed point scaling
                         sizeof(SceneVertex),         // total num bytes stored per vertex
                         off2);


   GLenum error = glGetError();
   if(GL_NO_ERROR != error)
   {
      NSLog(@"GL Error: 0x%x", error);
   }


   int sizeOfTries = sizeof(triangles);
   int sizeOfSceneVertex = sizeof(SceneVertex);

   int numArraysToDraw = sizeOfTries / sizeOfSceneVertex;

   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numArraysToDraw);

}
```

Comment: Are you enabling depth testing and depth writes and setting the depth test anywhere? Also, could you try disabling back face culling and see if that makes a difference (glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE))

Comment: the only line i have written concerning depth buffers is setting the drawableDepthFormat property.  is there a boolean somewhere to set on GLKView as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough just to have a depth buffer, you need to tell OpenGL how you want to use it. Try adding the following lines:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  // Enable depth testing
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);     // Enable depth write
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);   // Choose the depth comparison function
```

While we're here, I'd recommend GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24 over GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat16 for most use cases (better precision).

I'd also recommend familiarizing yourself with xcode's frame capture feature [(doc)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/debugging_opengl_es_frame.html), it really is an invaluable way to figure out what is going on when rendering is not working as intended.

Comment: `GL_TRUE` is the default for the depth mask, and `GL_LESS` (which will work at least as well as `GL_LEQUAL`) is the default for the comparison function. So only the first line is needed.

Comment: i added those lines, yet i can still see through the near triangles.  perhaps it has to do with lighting? and the lit fragments are not fully opaque?

Comment: Try adding glDisable(GL_BLEND) and glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE) to see if that helps.